# how to recieve Audio inputs in python and converts it to text string

Tags: python, audio, module, microphone

I think that my question clear from the title

Is there a python module or function that allows me to receive Audio inputs and return a text value?

For example if i used the microphone and said Hellow the python program returns "hellow" as text value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use PyAudio: https://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/pyaudio/ to capture audio from your speaker, then the speech recognition API: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/SpeechRecognition/ to convert audio to text.

Comment: [when i try to download pyaudio module this message appears in this photo][1]


  [1]: http://store6.up-00.com/2017-05/149583424330621.png